# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX analogue for u-boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I use `uname -a`:

> Linux orangepipc 3.4.113-sun8i #28 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 2 02:01:28 CET 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

and tried to solve the problem of unpredictable network interfaces' names (like `enx1c13bf8340af` (= enx + MAC address) instead of `wlan0`).

I found, that editing `/etc/default/grub` and changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"` is the solution of the problem (then `sudo update-grub`). But there is no `grub`. *Armbian* uses *u-boot* AIK.

How to pass a cmdline to linux using *u-boot*?

I know, that problem is common.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

- edit `bootargs` variable in `/boot/boot.cmd` - append `net.ifnames=0` to it.
- run `mkimage -C none -A arm -T script -d /boot/boot.cmd /boot/boot.scr`